# c# ler um arquivo XML de origem remota

Tags: c#, xml

tenho uma API que me gera um XML porém sempre que vou tentar pegar o XML para tratar do outro lado ele me retorna um erro.

o XML é esse:

```
<ArrayOfResponsaveis xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/webservice.Models">
<Responsaveis>
<id>1</id>
<matricula>uc14100703</matricula>
<nivel>1</nivel>
<nome>danilo dorgam</nome>
<senha>xxxx</senha>
</Responsaveis>
</ArrayOfResponsaveis>
```

o código que uso para ler o XML é esse

```
public Boolean setLogin(string matricula, string senha)
{
    string url = URL_WEBSERVICE+matricula+"/"+senha;
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@url);
    var lv1s = from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("Responsaveis")
               where (string) lv1.Element("id").Value == "1"
               select lv1;
    return false;
}
```

porém em `XDocument.Load` ele trava e mostra o seguinte erro

```
System.Xml.XmlException: 'Dados no nível raiz inválidos. Linha 1, posição 1.'
```

Comment: Qual é o erro ?

Comment: perdão, atualizei lá

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é o modo de ler os atributos, recomendo desserealizar para uma classe.

Um exemplo válido de uma classe para desserealizar seu xml em model
https://paste.ofcode.org/BDAVPU5T5sZ7xZ4kfjUmea

*OBS: Basta copiar o XML ir no visual studio > Edit > Paste especial > XML to class*

**Lendo o XML via web.**

```
using System.Net.Http;

var client = new HttpClient();
var uri = new Uri(url);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
```

**Método 1 - Serializando:**

```
var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayOfResponsaveis));
    return (ArrayOfResponsaveis)serializer.Deserialize(responseString);
```

**Método 2 - Lendo os atributos**

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(responseString);
    var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Responsaveis/*");

    foreach (XmlNode childNode in nodes)
    {
        switch (childNode.Name)
        {
         //logica
        }
    }
```